# How do I package the templates from react frontend into a Django app?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, react-redux, packaging

I'm trying to package a Django+react app into a reusable app to be installed into another Django project. I followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/reusable-apps/) to package it but after installing in a new project, I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error. I tried moving the build files out of the react app to a folder named templates inside the Django app and recursively including it in the Manifest. But when I install the app elsewhere, it keeps throwing a TemplateDoesNotExist error.
Here's my directory structure:

```
├── app
  ├── migrations
  ├── static
  │   ├── css
  │   ├── js
  │   └── media
  ├── templates
  └── tests
├── ui
    ├── public
    ├── src
```

Here's my MANIFEST.in:

```
include LICENSE
include README.rst
recursive-include ui *
recursive-include app/templates *
recursive-include app/static *
```

I've added the app in the new project's INSTALLED_APPS and ran migrations. I've also edited the urls in the new project's urls.py to include:

```
path('app/', include('app.urls')),
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

But when I run the server and try to send a GET request to any APIs within the installed app, I get a TemplateDoesNotExist with the following traceback.

```
Internal Server Error: /app/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/home/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/home/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html
```